# Equivalence of definition of symplectic form

Tags: proof-verification, exterior-algebra, symplectic-geometry

> Suppose that $V$ is a vector space of dimension $2n$, and let $\omega \in \Lambda^2(V)$. Prove that the following two statements are equivalent.
>
> (1)  $\tilde{\omega} : V \rightarrow V^*$ defined by $X\mapsto \omega(X,\cdot)$ is an isomorphism.
>
> (2) $\omega^n=\omega \wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega \in \Lambda^{2n}(V)$ is nonzero.

What I have tried is

> Suppose that  the map $\tilde{\omega}: V\rightarrow V^*$ defined by $X\rightarrow i_X \omega$ is an isomorphism. Then we have the basis $(e^1,f^1,e^2,f^2,\dots, e^n,f^n)$ of $V$ such that 
>   \begin{align*}
> &(1) \text{ }\omega(e^i,e^j)=\omega(f^i,f^j)=0 \hspace{3mm}\forall i,j\\
> &(2)\text{ } \omega(e^i,f^j)=\begin{cases} 1 &i=j\\ 0 &i\neq j \end{cases}.
> \end{align*}
>
> Then observe that
>
> \begin{align*}
> \omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega \in \Lambda^{2n}(V)
> \end{align*}
>
> and that
>
> \begin{align*}
> \omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega (e^1,f^1,e^2,f^2,\dots, e^n,f^n)=\omega(e^1,f^1)\wedge \omega(e^2,f^2)\wedge \cdots \omega(e^n,f^n)=1\neq 0.
> \end{align*}
>
> Therefore, $\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega $ is nonzero.\
>
> Conversely, suppose that $\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega \in \Lambda^{2n}(V)$ is nonzero. Clearly, note that $\tilde{\omega}:V\rightarrow V^*$ defined by $\tilde{\omega}(X)=i_X(\omega)$ is a homomorphism since $i_{X+Y}\omega(Z)=\omega(X+Y,Z)=\omega(X,Z)+\omega(Y,Z)=i_X\omega(Z)+i_Y\omega(Z)$. We need to prove that $\tilde{\omega}$ is a bijection.
>    And assume that $i_X(\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega)=0$ for some $X\in V\setminus \{0\}$. Then we can build a basis $\{X,r^1,r^2,\dots, r^{2n-1}\}$ of $V$. Since $\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega(X,r^1,r^2,\dots,r^{2n-1})=0$ and $\{X,r^1,r^2,\dots, r^{2n-1}\}$ is a basis of $V$, $\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega=0$ and it is a contradiction. Thus, $i_X(\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega)$ is nonzero for any $X\in V\setminus \{0\}$. Then note that, for given $X\in V\setminus \{0\}$, we have $Y\in V$ such that  $i_X\omega(Y)=\omega(X,Y)\neq 0$ (otherwise, for any collection $\{Y^1,\dots, Y^{2n-1}\}\subseteq V$, $i_X(\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega)(Y^1,\dots, Y^{2n-1})=0\wedge \omega(Y^{2},Y^{3})\wedge \dots \wedge \omega(Y^{2n-2},Y^{2n-1})=0$). Then $ker \tilde{\omega}=0$, so $\tilde{\omega}$ is an injection. Then since $V$ and $V^*$ has same dimension, $\tilde{\omega}$ is a surjection so is a bijection. Therefore, $\tilde{\omega}$ is an isomorphism.

I mistakenly used the **wrong computation of wedge product of alternating tensors**.
I am pretty sure that I can adjust a little bit from here to make solid proof. I am still thinking about but seems I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to think that for instance $(\omega \wedge \omega)(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) = \omega(X_1, X_2)\omega(X_3,X_4)$, but this is usually wrong as the wedges (the explicit one plus the implicit ones inside $\omega$) force you to evaluate on every permutations of the $X_i$'s. There are different conventions in use for the wedge discarding or not the redundant evaluations coming from the (anti)symmetry of $\omega$... In any case you should have obtained $factor * n! \neq 0$, and later a sum also with terms involving $Y^1$ in place of other $Y^j$'s should appear when you aim to prove injectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figure it out. I posted this solution for future.

Suppose that  the map $\tilde{\omega}: V\rightarrow V^*$ defined by $X\rightarrow i_X \omega$ is an isomorphism. Then we have the basis $(e^1,f^1,e^2,f^2,\dots, e^n,f^n)$ of $V$ such that 
\begin{align*}
&(1) \text{ }\omega(e^i,e^j)=\omega(f^i,f^j)=0 \hspace{3mm}\forall i,j\\
&(2)\text{ } \omega(e^i,f^j)=\begin{cases} 1 &i=j\\ 0 &i\neq j \end{cases}.
\end{align*}

Let $\{\epsilon^i,\delta^i\}$ be a dual basis such that 
\begin{align*}
&(1) \epsilon^i(e^j)=\begin{cases}1 &i=j \\0 &i\neq j  \end{cases} &(2) \delta^i(f^j)=\begin{cases}1 &i=j \\0 &i\neq j  \end{cases}\\
&(3) \epsilon^i(f^j)=0 \hspace{4mm}\forall i,j &(4) \delta^i(e^j)=0 \hspace{4mm}\forall i,j.
\end{align*}

Then observe that

\begin{align*}
\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega \in \Lambda^{2n}(V)
\end{align*}

and that, since $dim(\Lambda^{2n}(V))=\bigg(\begin{matrix}
2n\\2n
\end{matrix} \bigg)=1$,  for some integer $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$,

\begin{align*}
\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega (e^1,f^1,e^2,f^2,\dots, e^n,f^n)&=\alpha(\epsilon^1\wedge \delta^1\wedge \epsilon^2\wedge \delta^2\wedge\cdots \epsilon^n\wedge \delta^n)(e^1,f^1,e^2,f^2,\dots, e^n,f^n)\\ &=\alpha\sum_{\sigma}sgn(\sigma)\epsilon^1(v_{\sigma(1)})\delta^1(v_{\sigma(2)})\cdots \epsilon^n(v_{\sigma(2n-1)})\delta^n(v_{\sigma(2n)})\\
&=\alpha(\epsilon^1(e^1)\delta^1(f^1)\cdots \epsilon^n(e^n)\delta^n(f^n))\\
&=\alpha\neq 0,
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
v_i=\begin{cases} e^m &\text{ if }i=2m-1\\ f^m &\text{ if } i=2m  \end{cases} \hspace{2cm} \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}\cap [1,2n].
\end{align*}

Therefore, $\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega $ is nonzero.\

Conversely, suppose that $\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega \in \Lambda^{2n}(V)$ is nonzero. Clearly, note that $\tilde{\omega}:V\rightarrow V^*$ defined by $\tilde{\omega}(X)=i_X(\omega)$ is a homomorphism since $i_{X+Y}\omega(Z)=\omega(X+Y,Z)=\omega(X,Z)+\omega(Y,Z)=i_X\omega(Z)+i_Y\omega(Z)$. We need to prove that $\tilde{\omega}$ is a bijection.\

Assume that $i_X(\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega)=0$ for some $X\in V\setminus \{0\}$. and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ since $dim(\Lambda^{2n}(V))=1$. Then we can build a basis $\{X,r^1,r^2,\dots, r^{2n-1}\}$ of $V$. Then, $\forall v\in V$, $v$ can be represented as linear combination of the elements in basis. Then, for any $\{a^1,\dots, a^{2n}\}\subseteq V$, $\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega(a^1,\dots,a^{2n})=0$ since $\omega$ is multilinear map. It contradicts to our assumption. Therefore, $i_X (\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega)\neq 0$ $\forall X\in V\setminus \{0\}$. \

Let $X\in V\setminus \{0\}$ be given. Note that
 \begin{align*}
 i_X(\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega)= (i_X\omega)\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega+\cdots + \omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge (i_X\omega)=n\{ (i_X\omega)\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega \}\neq 0.
\end{align*}

It implies that $(i_X\omega)\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega\neq 0$, thus, we should have $(i_X\omega)\neq 0$. Thus, we have $Y\in V$ such that $(i_X\omega)(Y)=\omega(X,Y)\neq 0$. Since $X\in V\setminus \{0\}$ was arbitrary, $i_X\omega =0 \iff X=0$. Then $ker \tilde{\omega}=0$, so $\tilde{\omega}$ is an injection. Then since $V$ and $V^*$ has same dimension, $\tilde{\omega}$ is a surjection so is a bijection. Therefore, $\tilde{\omega}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I'd say that your original attempt was closer to a proof, since you really only had to take my comment on permutations into account. In this new attempt, to be thorough, you should explain why $\omega = \sum_i \epsilon^i \wedge \delta^i$. Then you should note that the 2-forms $\epsilon^i \wedge \delta^i$ commute, thus $\omega ^n$ can be evaluated via the multinomial theorem: you should get that $\omega^n = (n!) \prod_{i=1}^n (\epsilon^i \wedge \delta^i)$. Then regardless of the convention for the wedge, evaluation on $\prod_{i=1}^n e_i \wedge f_i$ is nonzero (btw $n$ already denotes dimension)

Comment: Next the basis $\{X, r^1, \dots, r^{2n-1}\}$ of $V$ induces the basis $\{X \wedge r^1 \wedge \dots \wedge r^{2n-1}\}$ of $\Lambda^n V$, so no real need to mention the $a^{j}$s. More importantly, it's not true that for any given nonzero $X$ there is $Y$ as you stated. And even if that were true, the terms $\epsilon^i(X) \delta^i(Y)$ could change sign so that $\omega(X,Y)$ could be zero. The only lack of your original attempt was to take account of the permutations, which would give you a *sum* of terms each vanishing because of the absurd hypothesis $i_X \omega = 0$.

Comment: @JordanPayette Thank you for letting me know the errors. I made many mistakes because I am new to alternating tensor products.  Anyway, I was trying to fix it based on your comment.   I could not follow some of your comments(i.e, $$\omega=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\epsilon^i\wedge \delta^i)$$) but it seems better and okay. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Oops! I should have written $\omega^n = n! \wedge_{i=1}^n (\epsilon^i \wedge \delta^i)$, meaning $\omega^n = (n!) \epsilon^1 \wedge \delta^1 \wedge \epsilon^2 \wedge \dots \wedge \delta^n$. Hopefully it's more sensible to you this way!